# How to add Date and Time to a SQL table using Ajax and JSON?

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to code a Check-In page. When the user types in 'admin' and the password 'pass' a date and time is created.
I'm then trying to save these dates and times in a table to keep a record of check in times for the users.
Can this be done through Ajax?
As it is, when the user signs in, the current date and time will be displayed on the page.

```
var rootURL = "http://localhost:8080/SCC/rest/checkin";

$(document).ready(function() {
    // on click Sign In Button checks that username =='admin'
    // and password == 'password'
    //var newD = newDate();
    
    $("#login").click(function() {
        if ($("#loginUserName").val() == 'admin' && $("#loginPassword").val() == 'pass') {
                $("#signIn").hide();
                newDate();
                addCheckIn();
                } else {
                    alert("Please try again")
                    }
                $("#logout").click(function() {
                    $("form")[0].reset();
                    $("#signIn").show();
                    $("#second").hide();
                });
                navigator.geolocation;
                const successfulLookup = (position) => {
                    const { latitude, longitude } = position.coords;
                    fetch('https://api.opencagedata.com/geocode/v1/json?q=${latitude}+${longitude}&key=42815d59fd754ae0a68c6efcdc90d09e')
                        .then(response => response.json())
                        .then(console.log);
                };

                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successfulLookup, console.log);
                
    });

var newDate = function(){
exd = new Date();
var hours=exd.getHours();
var min=exd.getMinutes();
var sec=exd.getSeconds();
var dat=exd.getDate();
var month=exd.getMonth();
var year=exd.getFullYear();
var dn="AM";
if(hours==12){
    dn="PM";
    }
if(hours>12){
    dn="PM";
    hours=hours-12;
    }
if(hours<10){
    hours="0"+hours;
    }
if(min<10){
    min="0"+min;
    }
if(sec<10){
    sec="0"+sec;
    }
if(dat<10){
    dat="0"+dat;
    }
if(month<10){
    month="0"+month;
    }
var clock = hours+":"+min+":"+sec+""+dn;
var datee = dat+"-"+ month+"-"+year;

$("#second").append("<p>Your Login Time is  </p> " + clock + "<p>Your Login Date is </p> " + datee);

}

var addCheckIn = function() {
console.log('addCheckIn');
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    contentType : 'application/json',
    url : rootURL,
    dataType : "json",
    data : formToJSON(),
    success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        alert('CheckIn Time Added');
    },
    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('CheckIn error: ' + textStatus);
    }
});
};

var formToJSON = function(){

return JSON.stringify({
    "checkInTime" : clock,
    "checkInDate" : datee
});
};

});
```

Comment: Why do all that work in javascript. a simple `NOW()` in your MySQL query will put a date and time into a tables column.

Comment: Also you dont want to store the Locale type formats in the MySQL database. Do that kind of date/time fiddling in the presentation layer by all means, but the format of a date on a MySQL database is `YYYY-MM-DD Hours:Min:Secs`

Comment: It's part of a webapp and I just want to store the values. Is it possible to just store them as Strings or would I need to convert them to the correct format?

Comment: You can store dates and times as string, they just become 10 times more difficult to use in SQL because you loose all the date and time functionality that you get for free with a DATE or TIME or DATETIME column type

Comment: Ok thanks, I won't actually be using them in SQL or manipulating them, I'll just want to be able to view the table as a whole for record keeping etc.